# Contradiction detection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-internals

I am trying to learn Table Partitioning. However, I struggling to understand why SQL Server behaving stage for a simple query.

## Test dataset

```
   /* --------------------------------------------------
-- Create helper function GetNums by Itzik Ben-Gan
-- http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers
-- GetNums is used to insert test data
-------------------------------------------------- */

-- Drop helper function if it already exists
IF OBJECT_ID('GetNums') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION GetNums;
GO

-- Create helper function
CREATE FUNCTION GetNums(@n AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
  WITH
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP (@n) n FROM Nums ORDER BY n;
GO

/* ------------------------------------------------------------
-- Create example Partitioned Table (Heap)
-- The Partition Column is a DATE column
-- The Partition Function is RANGE RIGHT
-- The Partition Scheme maps all partitions to [PRIMARY]
------------------------------------------------------------ */

-- Drop objects if they already exist
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = N'Sales')
    DROP TABLE Sales;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.partition_schemes WHERE name = N'psSales')
    DROP PARTITION SCHEME psSales;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.partition_functions WHERE name = N'pfSales')
    DROP PARTITION FUNCTION pfSales;

-- Create the Partition Function 
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pfSales (DATE)
AS RANGE right FOR VALUES 
('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01');

-- Create the Partition Scheme
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME psSales
AS PARTITION pfSales 
ALL TO ([Primary]);

-- Create the Partitioned Table (Heap) on the Partition Scheme
CREATE TABLE Sales 
(
    SalesDate DATE constraint ck_date check(SalesDate<'2016-01-01'),
    Quantity INT
) ON psSales(SalesDate);

-- Insert test data
INSERT INTO Sales(SalesDate, Quantity)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,dates.n-1,'2012-01-01') AS SalesDate, qty.n AS Quantity
FROM GetNums(DATEDIFF(DD,'2012-01-01','2016-01-01')) dates
CROSS JOIN GetNums(1000) AS qty;
```

**Qery**

```
select count(1) from sales where SalesDate>'20160101'
```

Please see the execution plan below.

[Execution Plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0uFffnwypYVa2YzRFVhdW82RWc/view?usp=sharing)

**Questions**

1. Why SQL doing CONVERT_IMPLICIT
2. Why SQL is not doing the contradiction detection to avoid the table scan.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why SQL doing CONVERT_IMPLICIT

Because you have a literal in the query that needs to be parsed and converted to a date. This is not a performance concern.

> SQL is not doing the contradiction detection to avoid the table scan.

With no indexes, a table scan is inevitable. However, as you can see from the table scan operator properties, a seek is used so only the partition containing the specified `SalesDate` value is scanned. Run the query with `STATISTICS IO ON` with and without the `WHERE` clause to see the impact of partition elimination:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sales WHERE SalesDate>'20160101';
Table 'Sales'. Scan count 1, logical reads 722, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sales;
Table 'Sales'. Scan count 4, logical reads 2890, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

The [partition aware seek operation was introduced in SQL Server 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345599%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Previously (SQL 2005), partition elimination was accomplished with separate execution plan operators.

**EDIT**
I just realized the main question was mostly about the check constraint than partition boundaries. I think this answer still provides some value so I won't delete it.

Comment: That's still 722 reads. Compared with 0 when `AND 1=1` is added.

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes, I didn't consider the check constraint when I first posted my answer. 722 is still better than 2890 :-)

Answer (score 9):

You're getting a trivial and simple parameterized plan for your simple query.

Add `AND 1 = (SELECT 1);` to the end of your query, and you'll get the constant scan/contradiction detection.

[image]

Using just `AND 1 = 1` doesn't always work if the aim is to also avoid trivial plans. See [Query Plans: Trivial Optimization vs Simple Parameterization](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/06/query-plans-trivial-optimization-vs-simple-parameterization/) by Erik Darling.

You should also get into the habit of being careful about data types. A string is not a date, and there is no special T-SQL syntax to specify a date literal. You can use [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to be explicit, e.g. `SalesDate > CONVERT(date, '20160101', 112)`.

Related reading: [Why Doesn’t Partition Elimination Work?](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422160838/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/09/12/why-doesn-t-partition-elimination-work.aspx) by Paul White.